How to load a text file to pyspark dataframe with rows having different schemas?
I have text files with the format like below, is there a way to load the entire text file (ALL COLUMNS) and then split out to handle the various schemas?  First column indicates the different schemas.
Source File.txt
A | 8/19/2024
B | 123 | ABC | ABC |
B | 123 | ABC | ABC |
C | ABC | ABC | 123 | 123
Code:
df = spark.read.format("csv").option("header","false").load("File.txt")
display(df)

Result:
| A        | 8/19/2024
| B        | 123
| B        | 123
| C        | ABC
